# Array.push.call on window / global and numeric properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, firefox, safari

When I run this line of code :

```
> var new_arr_length = Array.prototype.push.call(this, null);
```

I get very strange results.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) says that `push()` should return the length of the array to which push was applied to :

> **Returns**
>
> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

but this is what you get for :

```
> new_arr_length
```

- in Chrome you get `17` because initially, properties `0` to `15` of this (`window`) equal `"DOMException"`.
- in Node.js you get `1`. Here `this` would be the `global` object.
- in Safari you get `3` because initially, properties `0` and `1` of this (`window`) equal `Window`
- and in Firefox you get an `TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter` error

THis leads me to ask the following questions :

1. Why has Chrome `"DOMException"`s from `this[0]` to `this[15]` ?
2. Why has Safari `Window` for `this[0]` and `this[1]` ?
3. Why is Firefox the only one to throw a `TypeError` and other browsers happily execute `Array` methods on an `Object` ?

Of course this specific line of code is ugly and merely an experiment rather than something used in live projects.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: First of all you have to know that the specification only requires the  global object to have a handful of properties (http://es5.github.io/#x15.1), the environment can add any number of additional properties. Also, the global object is a *host object*, i.e. its behavior is only partially dictated by the specification. This all means that you have to expect that the global object has different properties in different environments.

Comment: Yeah I guessed that it had something to do with standards or in this case non-standard behaviours. The two things that seemed strange were that `1) Numeric properties contained references to the same thing in  seemingly random places` and `2) Some browsers let Window / Global behave like an Array and some (like Firefox) not. Which seems to be kind of a big difference.`.

Comment: In Latest Chrome, Opera, IE11 before pushing i got result of length 0 after 1. How you got those results?

Comment: In the latest Chrome version, `this.length` (where this is `window`), I get `17`. So that would be 16 `"DOMException"` from `this[0]` to `this[15]` and 1 `null` which is the value we pushed at `this[16]`.

Comment: Weird thing is that you are right @Givi. I get the same results as you when I'm on a normal page, but when I'm on the "new tab" page I get something else. Even weirder if you do the following `Object.keys(window[0])`, you get `SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "chrome-search://local-ntp" from accessing a cross-origin frame.`on Chrome.

Comment: Same in Opera, I think that in this way the browser makers trying to hide some important data for security reason. In IE11 you generally can't open developer tools in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1)  Normally, `window[n]` for n an integer would be the Window of the n-th subframe on the page.  That's what Givi is seeing in the comments on a page with no frames: length of 0, and no indexed properties and what you're seeing in Safari.

2)  On the Chrome "new tab" page there's a bunch of `<iframe>` tags.  17 of them, over here.  Quickly looking at it, `window[0]` through `window[16]` are in fact Window object for those subframes, on that page.  I have no idea why you see DOMException instead.

3)  The Array methods, including `Array.prototype.push`, are mostly generic.  That is, their definition is such that they work on any object, not just on an Array.  If you look at the spec at http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.push you'll see that all `push` does is get the `.length` if the this object, then set `n` to that length, then for each of the passed arguments set `thisObj[n] = argument` (sort of; see item 4 below) and increment `n` by 1.  And then at the very end set `this.length = n`.  These are all operations that generally make sense on any object.

4) If you look carefully at how `push` is actually defined, what it *actually* does to set property `n` is `Put(O, ToString(n), E, true)`.  If you look at http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-put-o-p-v-throw you will see that the last argument is whether to throw an exception if the `[[Set]]` call fails.  Now if you actually try setting indexed properties on Window in Firefox, the sets in fact fail.  In strict mode you get exceptions; in non-strict mode the sets are silent no-ops.  This is in fact the behavior required by the WebIDL specification at http://heycam.github.io/webidl/#defineownproperty (in particular step 1 substep 4 if the index has no child window at it, and step 1 substep 5 if the index does have a child window at it, since Window has neither an indexed property setter nor an indexed property creator).  The other browsers just haven't implemented this part of the spec yet, presumably.  I should note that Firefox doesn't implement it perfectly either.  It used to throw in this case, as you note, on the `Put(O, "length", n, true)` in fact, but current nightlies do not because `length` was fixed to be a replaceable property, so it can in fact be set.  But once https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=828137 is fixed it will throw again.